# Cant download any pictures/files/movies from the Internet on my Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, video, downloading, images

Yesterday I downloaded a video online from the Internet on my Samsung Galaxy S2. When it took too long time, I stopped the download and pressed deactivate and force stop. I tried to download the video again, but it would not download to my phone.
I tried to restart the phone, and download some pictures or other videos but there is nothing downloading to my phone. When I press "save link" on a picture to download the picture, it comes up a messasge "starts downloading", but nothing happends and I have looked everywhere to find the picture.

What can I do to make it download again?

Comment: Please share which video you are trying to download. Atleast tell use the websites where you try to download pics from.

Comment: I will come back to you with a link for the video. The pictures are from www.weheartit.com Earlier when I have downloaded images from we heart it, it has been no problem. COMMENT

Comment: Is your internet connection fast enough to download files ?
What Android version do you have ?